# How to show and hide paragraphs using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, fadein, fadeout

I want to show and hide using JQuery methods.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ whats the problem?

Comment: Do you? And what did you try? A statement is not a question, and you haven't explained the problems you've had, or might be having.

Comment: You appear to have used the correct jQuery methods as tags in the question, so you know what functions to use...

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please first search for the questions you have and then ask, if you don't get an answer. See [ask]?

Answer (score 3):

use .show()
and .hide() methods

```
$("#id").show("fold",{},1000);
$("#id").hide("fold",{},1000);
```

refer:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/

Answer (score 1):

Use .show() and .hide()

for example, to hide it:

```
<p class="myParagraph">This is some paragraph that you want to hide</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myParagraph').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your paragrAPHS IN

and try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('button_hide_show').click(function(){
         $("p").toggle();
  });
})
```

Comment: Toggle function can do both the show(),hide()  functionalities